# How does the jQuery - ContentType tell javascript the specific data I want to display?

Tags: jquery, ajax

So jQuery documentation state that the default for **contentType** is **'application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.  I was making a call to a web method that returned a bool, but if I specified **dataType** as **'json'** and **didn't** specify the **contentType** (expecting it to default) I could see in debug that a string was returned that included my bool (but more data as well).

But if I specified **application/json; charset=utf-8** it would just return the bool (or at least after it parsed the return data).

So my larger question besides the question in the title - how do I determine the **dataType** and **contentType** when determining what I want to get back from a web method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

contentType tells the server what type of data you are sending it.  dataType tells jQuery what type to expect the server to return.  If dataType is set to json, then jQuery will parse the response from the server to a json Object.

Depending on what server technology you are using, contentType may or may not matter.  But it's always best to specify if you are unsure.

Comment: Thanks.  However, if I am specifying JSON, why is the returned data different if I specify the default of contentType versus application/json?  Also, I am looking for any type of "best practice" or "helpful way" to figure out what I should set based on what I might be getting back?  For example, when I specified different options I would get a long string with allot of additional data other than just the bool.

Comment: It depends on which server you're using.  asp.net requires a content type of "application/json; charset=utf-8" before json can be returned from the web method.  I suspect the other data may have been an error message.